# Managing (release) and (product) provisioning profiles and certificates

Tags: xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile

This is my first time cloning a repo for a project that is on the store and using apns (not my app).

In Github I cloned the repo using the clone to Xcode option and it's in my local directory. Naturally they have a team of devs and certificates and company profile already set up.

When I open the Xcode project the signing (Debug) (Release) (Product) Provisioning Profiles in Xcode are red.

I cannot just use my own Apple ID Team profile right? So do I need to ask them for their keys or certs so I can copy them to the local cloned project directory?

The app uses apns. When I test and run the app how do I have authorization to run that app on my device? Do they also need my device ID?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the ***certificate*** along with ***key*** exported in .p12 format from the person who has created it or you should log in to their developer account and create a new certificate and using that certificate create new provisioning profile.

To run the app in your device, that device must be added in the device list and should be included in the **provisioning profile**.

There is ***`automatic signing`*** in option available using the personal developer account, using that xcode itself create certificate, but since you are using `APNS` i don't think that can be used.

Comment: Some share the developer account and some would share certificate and provisioning profiles.You can refer this for more details regarding profile and ceritficate. https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/what-is-a-provisioning-profile-in-ios-77987a7c54c2

Comment: Refer this also https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-code-signing-provisioning-in-a-nutshell-d5b247760bef

Comment: Yes .. On double clicking the .p12.. It will be added to the key chain.

Comment: Yes all app need their own certificates. iOS have a new feature to authenticate APNS via KEY (One Single Key for the entire developer account no matter of app or environment)  If you have developer account access you can create certificate your own

Comment: Don't know about the push integration in watchOS. If you are developing a new app then you will require 2 certificates, one of sandbox and other of production.

Comment: So I eventually received their AppleID/team invitation which made everything easier using automatic code signing. iOS side is done. But I still need to create 3 watchOS certs. `Development APNs SSL sandbox`, `Product APNs SSL sandbox`, `WatchKit Services`. They shared their p12 but I cannot use that p12 because there is not a watchOS app ID associated with it right? I have to add the watch target first using their teamID, give that target an app ID, then generate a new p12 yea? When I generate the certificates I will use my own Keychain. It doesn't matter if I'm using my own keychain?

Answer (score 1):

If they are using automatic code signing, and having you work on the project, you should request them to invite you to their team.  Give them your Apple ID email address and they can add you as a team member.  Then, when you build, Xcode will automatically generate a new Development certificate and provisioning profile, complete with all the app IDs, entitlements, etc. that you need.

Depending on the role they gave you, you will likely only be able codesign the app for development, not distribution.  **Team members** can generate code signing identities for iOS Development, meaning installation and running on test devices that have their device IDs added to the development profile.  **Team members** cannot generate or request certs or profiles for iOS Distribution (for submitting to the app store or TestFlight). Devs with the **team admin** role can generate or download the iOS Distribution cert and profiles.  IF you are not going to be the one submitting to the store, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have a team admin role. Automatic code signing on the iOS side. But I will be adding a watchOS target to their iOS project so I will be creating 3 watch certificates. To clarify, I will be creating the certs using my team admin profile (for the purpose of generating a development provisioning profile?) How does that work when you're using your own keychain Access app and doing all the exporting?

Comment: It should create signing identities for the watchOS target for you.  If you want others on the team to be able to build the distribution release of the watch OS target, you can export the cert / private key that was created and provide it to the team members.  With automatic code signing, Xcode should download the profile / cert if needed, but you would need to provide them with at least the private key.

Comment: Sure if I select auto code signing it will auto sign for me. But I have to create those 3 certs myself manually via dev portal. Sorry, why would I be exporting certs and keys for them? They are using the same team signing. p.s. aren't these 3 certs eventually getting put on our server?

Comment: We don't use automatic code signing, so maybe someone else can weigh in.  But For our account, Apple only allows 2 iOS Distribution certificates.  If each team member generates their own, you would quickly run out.  The certificate and provisioning profile exist on Apple's site, but for your protection, Apple does not store the private key for the certificate.  So you would need to store that someplace securely, and each team member needing to run a release build would need that private key.